# What does this code do? Delphi asm

Tags: assembly

I try to parse encrypted &RQ history, but i really can't understand asm code. It is embedded to Delphi function.

Can somebody help me to understand this?

```
procedure decritt(var s:string; key:integer);
 asm
 mov ecx, key
 mov dl, cl
 shr ecx, 20
 mov dh, cl

 mov esi, s
 mov esi, [esi]
 or  esi, esi    // nil string
 jz  @OUT

// now esi points to the first character of the string

 mov ah, 10111000b

 mov ecx, length(s)
 or  ecx, ecx
 jz  @OUT
@IN:
 mov al, [esi]
 xor al, ah
 rol al, 3
 xor al, dh
 sub al, dl

 mov [esi], al
 inc esi
 ror ah, 3
 dec ecx
 jnz @IN
@OUT:
 end; // decritt
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This c++ code would be equivalent:

```
void encrypt(std::string s, int key) {

    const char dl = key;
    const char dh = key >> 20;
    char ah = 0xB8;

    for (int i=0; i<s.length(); ++i) {
        char c = s[i];
        c ^= ah;
        c = (c<<3)|(c>>5); // rotate a char three bits left
        c ^= dh;
        c -= dl;
        s[i] = c;
        ah = (ah>>3)|(ah<<5);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks right, but doesn't work. Don't know why.

The key is 300109517, the resulting string should be "hello world", the encrypted string is "\xdd\x92\x06\xb8\xcf\x0f\x65\x81\x9c\xf3\x07"

Comment: You can step through it with a debugger for an iteration or two and watch the rgisters al, ah. See if their values match the values of the equal named variables in my C program.

Answer (score 1):

Yay, finally i got it working. Here is the resulting python code:

```
def decrypt(self, string, key):
    decrypted = []

    dl = key & 0xffff
    dh = key >> 20
    ah = 0xb8

    for i in xrange(0, len(string)):
        c = ord(string[i])
        c ^= ah & 0xff
        c = ((c<<3)|(c>>5)) & 0xff
        c ^= dh & 0xff
        c = (c - dl) & 0xff

        decrypted.append(chr(c & 0xff))
        ah = ((ah>>3)|(ah<<5)) & 0xff

    return "".join(decrypted)
```

Answer (score 0):

The assembly function takes an encrypted string and the decrypt key. Using some fixed mathematical operations with the key it, decrypts the string. I found a Delphi example that does the same, yet simpler;

http://www.delphifaq.com/faq/delphi/strings/f95.shtml

You could convert ekini's Python code to Delphi to get rid of the asm code in your Delphi application if that is what you want.